# Telnet between two linux machines on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2

I am not a networking guy, so I apologize if my question is dumb.

I have two Ubuntu machines setup via Amazon EC2. I need to "talk" from one to the other over port 3000. On my receiving machine, I ran the following from the command-line.

```
netstat -ntlup | grep 3000
```

On my client machine, I ran the following from the command-line.

```
telnet [otherIPAddress] 3000
```

After some time, the client machine simple displayed:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

This would imply that port 3000 is not open on the receiving machine. For that reason, I ran the following command on the receiving machine:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp to any port 3000
```

I then tried again and got the same error. I then verified that my security group in EC allowed for incoming traffic on port 3000 over TCP. I still got the same error.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I really need to be able to telnet between these two machines.

Thank you!

Comment: Is telnetd (daemon) running? Anyway why you wouldn't use SSH instead? Telnet is INSECURE.

Comment: I'm just using Telnet as a quick and dirty test. What's the SSH approach? I'm open to anything. I just need to figure out how to get the connection open between the two machines.

Comment: is there anything listening to port 3000 on the server (result of the `netstat` command)? you can use `netcat` for that: `nc -l 3000`

Comment: When I use netcat, I see no response in the command-line. It just sits there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be working as expected however, whatever is running on `[otherIPAddress]:3000` is not expecting `Hello World\n` so it dropped the connection.